# How to set Default Browser on Ubuntu from command line?

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with Fluxbox.

Since I installed Chromium-browser, it has been set as the default system browser (don't know why, don't know when, maybe I clicked accept somewhere without paying attention). Now every web link I click (for example from Skype), Chromium will be opened instead of Firefox.

**How can I make Firefox my system default browser?**

I need to set this preference using the **command line**.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the terminal, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

This will provide a list of installed browsers, similar to the following (which is mine):

```
There are two alternatives which provide `x-www-browser'.
Selection    Path                         Priority    Status
-------------------------------------------------------------
* 1          /usr/bin/chromium-browser    40          auto mode
  2          /usr/bin/firefox             40          manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Just hit the selection number for the browser you want.

Comment: And how can I change the default browser to "Chromium" always using bash, without getting its number first?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen `sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium-browser`, there is also a command to list all alternatives in the form of `--list name`. Check out the manpage.

Comment: If the browser you want isn't in the list, you can do `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /path/to/browser 200`.